# Why htaccess not working for mobile browser?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have website (mzadkm.com) try to RewriteRule short url to app.php page .

So if user browse "mzadkm.com/app" will show "mzadkm.com/app.php" page

```
RewriteRule ^/app /app.php [L,R=301]
```

It's work on Computer , but on mobile browser give me 404 page

Any ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteRule ^/?app /app.php [L]
```

The documentation clearly says, that the pattern in a `RewriteRule` get's applied to the *relative* path of the request if the rule is implemented inside a *distributed* configuration file. That means you actually want to match the path `app` and *not* `/app` here. Which is why your rule did not get applied. The `^/?app` is a variant to accept *both* path notations, relative and absolut, which means the same rule can get implemented in the central configuration or likewise in a distributed configuration file (".htaccess").

I took the liberty to also remove the external redirection you showed ("R=301") since that most likely is *not* what you want, according to the phrasing of your question. Instead you want an *internal rewrite* .

You need to take care however that you do not implement a rewriting loop. Which would result in failing requests and an "internal server error" (http status 500).

One approach would be that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?app$ /app.php [L]
```

Here another one:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?app /app.php [L]
```

Why things looked fine on your computer, but not on a mobile browser is unclear. Since the same rules get applied and the requests look the same there has to be another reason for that. I suspect you looked at a cached result of a previous attempt somewhere. Remember to *always* use a fresh anonymous browser window when testing. And to check the response you receive back inside your browsers network console.

Comment: @EsmailAlGathuth Great to hear that! YeeHaw! Did you take a look into the documentation now? Do that, really. It is of excellent quality, comes with great examples and should be your first stop for additional information. You cannot simply "use" things you paste from somewhere without understanding what those snippets actually do.

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: I posted thank you as a comment , but not show up

Comment: You did, I answered to that comment. It has been deleted now, why ever. All fine.